# Hibernate JPA @Generated annotation compile error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm starting a maven/hibernate project using eclipse, and I'm having an issue with my metamodel classes.

I'm getting a red x for lines dealing with the `@Generated` annotation:

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
```

I've reviewed [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html#_usage_within_the_ide) and it describes an option `addGeneratedAnnotation`:

```
If set to true the processor will add the @Generated to the generated Java source file. Adding this annotation using JDK 5 will cause a compilation error. In this case set the flag to false. The default for this option is true
```

where do I set that option in eclipse? In the run config? I tried that, doing just a maven compile, but that did not fix it. Which maven goal will generated new metamodel classes.

I'm pretty sure I have the build path and factory path set up right. I am using java 9.

I have my pom.xml file to include the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**update**

I tried running `package` and `compile` in maven, but was getting the version error 52.0/53.0.

```
has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

I was able to resolve by setting compiler level and project facet java level to 1.8.

Is there a way to get this set up with later versions?

Comment: Are you using Java lower than 5?

Comment: no, using java 9

Comment: what is `JAVA_HOME` pointing to?

Comment: using eclipse, so JRE is set up in build bath, using jdk `openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17`

Comment: it doesn't matter, can you answer my question?

Comment: Also did you check compilance level to java 9 in properties in eclipse?

Comment: echo $JAVA_HOME doesn't show a value, working on linux, so not sure if that makes a difference. java -version shows what I pasted above. Also, in eclipse I usually change the JRE in the build path, so I thought that overwrote whatever was in JAVA_HOME, but not sure if I'm correct about that.

Comment: You need to set Window>Preferences>Java>Compiler>Compiler compilance level to 9

Comment: as per the comment above, I had that set up in the eclipse compiler settings, and had the errors described in the main body of the question. I then tried to run maven package compile and got the version 52.0/53.0 error shown above...I then changed compiler version (in eclipse) to 1.8 and that seemed to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

you need to import the hibernate library if you are using Maven yse this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>{hibernate.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

for gradle

```
org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.1.Final
```

or add the hibernate library to your project manually

Answer (score 0):

Try add this maven dependency in your pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>{hibernate.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

After that remove the @Generated of your classes and execute:

```
 mvn package
```

The Modelgen will generate your metamodel in target/...

The local where the metamodel has generated should be in your classpath.

Comment: I have that node in my pom.xml already. tried removing the @Generated annotations, and then ran maven with package and compile as goals